# What is the order of setting properties in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBlock` with two properties (`Text` and `Foreground`) bound to the same ViewModel property.

Both also have converters. One of the converters checks the `Text` property and returns a 'dash' if the value is `NaN`. The other checks that the value is above, below or equals zero and accordingly sets the foreground to different colors.

XAML example:

```
<TextBlock>

       <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding Path="AvgDistance" StringFormat="{}{0:N1}"                        
                  Converter="{x:Static converter:ValueToDash.Instance}"/>
       </TextBlock.Text>        

       <TextBlock.Foreground>                                                    
          <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static converter:ValueToColor.Instance}">                                                       
             <Binding Path="AvgDistance"/>
             <Binding ElementName="currentPeriod" Path="IsChecked" />
           </MultiBinding>
       </TextBlock.Foreground>  

</TextBlock>
```

Now I need that the ValueToDash converter fired **before** the ValueToColor converter, but it is always vice versa.

The `Foreground` property seems to be always set first, and only then the `Text` property is set.

Why is it so? And is it possible to reverse the order of setting?

Comment: IIRC, a converter isn't changing the bound value, it changes what is displayed (or sent to the dependencyproperty). Is the ValueToColor dependent on what you converted the value to? Maybe you can bind your foreground to `Text` instead of `AvgDistance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the order in which the properties are being set.

What you could do instead is to add another binding to your `MultiBinding` that binds to the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock>

    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="AvgDistance" StringFormat="{}{0:N1}"                        
                  Converter="{x:Static converter:ValueToDash.Instance}"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>

    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static converter:ValueToColor.Instance}">
            <Binding Path="AvgDistance"/>
            <Binding ElementName="currentPeriod" Path="IsChecked" />
            <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>

</TextBlock>
```

Then the `ValueToColor` converter will be invoked (again) whenever the `Text` property is set to some new value.