# Unhandled exception handler won't work in VS 2019

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement an Unhandled Exception handler for my WPF application.

App.xaml:

```
DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
 private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Faulty code to trigger unhandled exception
        string s = null;
        s.Trim();
    }
```

I'm stuck, this won't work. Instead of showing an error message, faulty code would return me to the Visual Studio Code Editor window and highlight the erroneous line.

**Update:** I have already tried adding the faulty code to a button click event rather than Window Load, but the same issue persisted.

```
btnClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Have you tried with an exception which is triggered *after* your `MainWindow` has been constructed? I suspect this *may* just be an ordering issue - that the window is constructed before the event handler is subscribed.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I've tried. But it too didn't work.

Comment: [`Application.MainWindow` is a `Window`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.mainwindow?view=net-5.0), so your `MainWindow` must have been instantiated before it's assigned to this property. If this happens before `DispatcherUnhandledException` is set (and you [shouldn't rely on the order that properties are set in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331809/what-is-the-order-of-setting-properties-in-xaml)), then no handler will be installed when your exception is thrown.

Comment: Please give more details of what you tried (in terms of a more "normal" timing for an exception, e.g. in response to a button press) then. Also, what happens if you just hit "continue" in the debugger? Is it possible that everything is working fine, and it's just a matter of the debugger firing before the event handler? What happens if you run the code *not* in the debugger?

Comment: @JonSkeet Instead of the Window Load event, I tried adding the code to a button event but the same issue persisted `btnClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: It would be good to put that information *in the question* instead of just in comments. And what about the rest of my comment? I wouldn't be at all surprised if this were just a matter of the debugger getting in before the event handler... which is useful sometimes, and not useful other times.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahan, you was very much right... I'm sorry, I missed crucial parts of your other comments.

1. Clicking the Continue button in the Debugger indeed raises my own "Unhandled Exception" error message! So yes, the Debugger is firing before the event handler.

2. Running the code WITHOUT debugger raises my error perfectly!!!

Could you please post it as an answer, so that I'll mark it as "answered"? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a matter of the debugger intervening before your event handler marks the exception as handled.

Just hit "continue" in the debugger, and the event handler will be triggered as normal. (You may also be able to configure how specific exceptions are handled in VS Code - I know you can in VS, but I don't know about VS Code.)